# Merging VHDS checkpoint files that won't merge

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have a VHDS file that I took a checkpoint of, but I can't merge the checkpoint file. I have tried the GUI (Hyper-V Manager->Edit Disk) and Powershell (Merge-VHD), to no avail. It gives the error "If the merge succeeds, the system will still be unable to delete the file".

This is on a Server 2016 Hyper-V failover cluster, and the VHDS is shared between a Server 2016 failover cluster file server role. This VHDS has a capacity of 20TB and is currently around 10TB, with a 500GB checkpoint file.

I had this same issue with a couple of smaller VHDS files. I ended up converting the main avhdx file to a VHDX file, then created a new VHDS file and selected the option to copy the contents of the new VHDX file. This file is so large I'm afraid it would take a good 24 hours to do the conversion and new VHDS file. I would prefer to not have that kind of downtime.

Does anyone know of a better way to accomplish this without these two lengthy steps? I've read that the avhdx is very similar to a regular VHDX, would it be risky (in terms of data corruption) to just rename that file to a VHDX and create a new VHDS from that VHDX?